# Custom errors e.g more than 1 record when using Codeigniter method

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

I have a codeigniter application.

My controller calls a function of a method.
I am checking if the row it is trying to select actually exists, and then returning true (and data) or false (and error message) respectively to my controller.

Within my controller there are multiple calls to this function.

I only want to load the 'success' view if all of these method calls return true.
Otherwise i want to display an error..

Given that i want to show the error within my layout, i could simply create an error view and pass an error message to it.. if there are multiple errors i want to display them all..

Is the correct/most efficient way to do this simply:

```
if($resultone['result'] == FALSE or $resulttwo['result'] == FALSE)
{
    $data['error']['0']=$resultone['error'];
    $data['error']['1']=$resulttwo['error'];

    $this->load->view('custom_error',$data);
} else {
    //load success view
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather do this:

```
$data = array(
  'data'   => array(),
  'errors' => array()
);
...
$result = call_that_function($arg1);
if (isset($result['error'])) {
  $data['errors'][] = $result['error'];
} else {
  $data['data'][] = $result['data'];
}
...
$result = call_that_function($arg2);
if (isset($result['error'])) {
  $data['errors'][] = $result['error'];
} else {
  $data['data'][] = $result['data'];
}
...
$result = call_that_function($arg3);
if (isset($result['error'])) {
  $data['errors'][] = $result['error'];
} else {
  $data['data'][] = $result['data'];
}
...
if (count($errors['errors']) > 0) {
  $this->load->view('custom_error',$data);
} else {
  $this->load->view('success',$data);
}
```

Comment: Long time has passed but curious as to some additional thoughts.. this seems like a very long winded way of handling errors as you have to add the above 'error handling' code to every controller - is there any better way?

Comment: feel free to create a helper or base controller with this method

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate a little further - I do not understand your meaning. Cheers